# How do I connect a point in one layer to a polygon in another layer, and have them appear when the point is selected or identified?

Tags: qgis, polygon

In QGIS I am creating a map of nonprofit organizations in Costa Rica, and I would like link each nonprofits headquarters to its zone of impact (not necessarily in the same area), so that when the headquarters is selected or identified, the zone of impact appears as well. I currently have a point layer with all the nonprofit headquarters mapped out, and a polygon layer with all the different areas of impact mapped out. How can a link a specific nonprofit in the headquarter in the point layer to its associated area of impact  polygon? [image: zone of impact nonprofit layer][image: headquarters layer]

Comment: Go to Vector>Data Management >Join attributes by location (step 7 here https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)

Comment: Will this work even though there are many overlapping impact zones, and the headquarters are not always located within the polygon impact zones?